# How to update an HTML control from code within SilverLight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

How can I update a textbox or label (specfically an asp.net control) text property from the code in the silverlight control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it calling javascript function from silverligt.
Shortly it looks like this:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("globalJSMethod", stringParam);
```

Note that javascript method must be accessable from window - window.globalJSMethod(...)
Check this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to see in details how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

**Suggested solution**:

I suppose that you could try to do it in two steps:

- write a javascript function that updates a control based on a given parameter, let's name it `updateControl`:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function updateControl(newValue)
      {
          //update your control here with newValue parameter with javascript
          ...
      }
  </script>
  ```
- in your Silverlight application (in the place you want to invoke the control value change) you should write:

  ```
  HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("updateControl", "this is a new value")
  ```

**Another solution for page update only**:

If you just need to refresh the page to get the value from other place, you can write in your Silverlight code:

```
HtmlPage.Document.Submit()
```

In the postback, you could get this data and show it in the control.

References and useful resources:

- ScriptObject.Invoke Method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.scriptobject.invoke%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
- Walkthrough: Calling JavaScript from Managed Code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
- Silverlight and JavaScript interop basics: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/06/Silverlight-and-JavaScript-Interop-Basics.aspx
- How to set the value of a form element using Javascript: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml